# Robocopy /purge not purging and /XD not excluding directories?

Tags: robocopy

I'm trying to build Robocopy scripts to replicate my old synctoy but I seem to have something wrong with my syntax.

With the below command I want to exclude ..\local settings\Temp and ... \local settings\Application Data
I'm also trying to /Purge the destination NAS of those directories.

```
robocopy C:\users\dancedad \\dancedadnas\workbackups\Laptop /mir /XD /e "C:\Users\dancedad\AppData" /z /mt:16 /w:5 /r:3 /XD "C:\users\dancedad\Local Settings\Temp" /XD "C:\users\Dancedad\Local Settings\Application Data" /XF *.tmp /PURGE /log:C:\users\Dancedad\documents\robolog.txt /SAVE:LaptopSync
```

The output robolog.txt seems to show the Exc Directories, but then when you look at the log, it is still mirroring from that path?  And instead of purging, I'm getting *Extra Dir entries.

```
>-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
>-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>  Started : Tuesday, May 16, 2023 07:31:08
>   Source : C:\users\DanceDad\
>     Dest : \\DanceDadNas\workbackups\Laptop\
>
>    Files : *.*
>       
>Exc Files : *.tmp
>       
> Exc Dirs : C:\Users\DanceDad\AppData
>       C:\users\DanceDad\Local Settings\Temp
>       C:\users\DanceDad\Local Settings\Application Data
>       C:\users\DanceDad\Application Data\discord
>       
>  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /Z /MT:16 /R:3 /W:5 
>
>------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       Newer                865    C:\users\DanceDad\My Documents\robolog.txt
>100%  
>
>     *EXTRA File         189753    \\DanceDadNas\workbackups\Laptop\.cisco\vpn\log\UIHistory_20230515_162859_log.txt
>       Newer                157    C:\users\DanceDad\Application Data\Slack\local-settings.json
>100%  
>       Newer                  0    C:\users\DanceDad\Dropbox\.dropbox.cache\marker_file
>100%  
>       Newer                 64    C:\users\DanceDad\Local Settings\ESRI_Licensing\README.txt
>100%  
>       Newer             821425    C:\users\DanceDad\Local Settings\Discord\Discord_updater_rCURRENT.log
>100%  
>       Newer             225280    C:\users\DanceDad\Local Settings\Discord\installer.db
>100%  
>       Newer             364757    C:\users\DanceDad\Local Settings\LogiOptionsPlus\settings.backup
>100%  
>       Newer             364782    C:\users\DanceDad\Local Settings\LogiOptionsPlus\settings.json
>100%  
>   *EXTRA Dir        -1    \\DanceDadNas\workbackups\Laptop\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\KF34TA3A\
>   *EXTRA Dir        -1    \\DanceDadNas\workbackups\Laptop\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\IE\KF34TA3A\
>   *EXTRA Dir        -1    \\DanceDadNas\workbackups\Laptop\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\L3QGXQV9\
>   *EXTRA Dir        -1    \\DanceDadNas\workbackups\Laptop\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\IE\L3QGXQV9\
>       Newer             159744    C:\users\DanceDad\Local Settings\WebEx\CiscoMeetings.db
>100%  
>       Newer              10354    C:\users\DanceDad\Recent\CustomDestinations\a55ed4fbb973aefb.customDestinations-ms
>100%  
>       Newer                 24    C:\users\DanceDad\Recent\CustomDestinations\f18460fded109990.customDestinations-ms
>100%  
>       Newer               2246    C:\users\DanceDad\Application Data\Microsoft\Credentials\FB4C8F2787CF103F364B7EC977B70EED
>100%  
>       Newer             16.2 m    C:\users\DanceDad\Application Data\Microsoft\Teams\logs.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/e` must not be between `/XD` and the path to exclude:

```
robocopy ... /XD /e "C:\Users\dancedad\AppData" ...
```

As you obviously intent to create empty directories this probably has been your intention:

```
robocopy ... /e /XD "C:\Users\dancedad\AppData" ...
```

and results in:

```
robocopy C:\users\dancedad \\dancedadnas\workbackups\Laptop /mir /e /XD "C:\Users\dancedad\AppData" /z /mt:16 /w:5 /r:3 /XD "C:\users\dancedad\Local Settings\Temp" /XD "C:\users\Dancedad\Local Settings\Application Data" /XF *.tmp /PURGE /log:C:\users\Dancedad\documents\robolog.txt /SAVE:LaptopSync
```